# R: Summing the even terms in a Fibonacci Sequence with warnings

Tags: r

I've been set a question on the Fibonacci Sequence and although I've been successful in doing the sequence, I haven't been as lucky summing the even terms up (i.e. 2nd, 4th, 6th... etc.) My code is below as well as the part of the question I am stuck on. Any guidance would be brilliant!
Question:
Write a function which will take as an input `x` and `y` and will return either the sum of the first `x` even Fibonacci numbers or the sum of even Fibonacci numbers less than `y`.
That means the user will be able to specify either `x` or `y` but not both.
You have to return a warning if someone uses both numbers (decide
on the message to return)
Code:

```
y <- 10
fibvals <- numeric(y)
fibvals[1] <- 1
fibvals[2] <- 1
for (i in 3:y) { 
   fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]
    if (i %% 2) 
  v<-sum(fibvals[i])
}
v
```

Comment: Please give us inputs and desired outputs.

Comment: You should do this operation out of the loop for both for efficiency and in order avoiding overriding the value. Just do `sum(fibvals[c(F,T)])` after the loop ends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started since this sounds like an exercise.

I would split your loop up into steps rather than do the summing within the loop with an `if` statement. Since you already have the sequence code working, you can just return what is asked for by the user. The `missing` function would probably help you out here

```
f <- function(x, y) {
  if (missing(y)) {
    warning('you must give y')
    y <- 10
  }
  fibvals <- numeric(y)
  fibvals[1] <- 1
  fibvals[2] <- 1
  for (i in 3:y) { 
    fibvals[i] <- fibvals[i-1]+fibvals[i-2]
  }

  evens <- fibvals %% 2 == 0
  odds <- fibvals %% 2 != 0

  if (missing(x)) {
    return(sum(fibvals[evens]))
  } else return(fibvals)
}

f(y = 20)
# [1] 3382
f(10)
# [1]  1  1  2  3  5  8 13 21 34 55
# Warning message:
# In f(10) : you must give y
```